# Delete Facebook apprequest (using javascript sdk) after a user has been taken to canvas page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-app-requests

I know I need to delete the apprequests after a user has clicked on them, but I can't figure out how to time it right using the Javascript SDK for Facebook.

Right now, I can get the apprequests to delete immediately after they are created, which obviously isn't good because the apprequests vanish before the user has the chance to click on them.

How do I detect that a user has accepted the apprequest, and where do I put my code to respond to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/apprequests

this code removes all requests your app sent to the current user(put it in your default page)

this is not best but because i'm not familiar with your coding this is all i did

this code only works if user installed your app

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<script>

      FB.api('/me/apprequests', function(response) {
        var ids = [];
        for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
          FB.api('/' + response.data[i].id, 'DELETE', Log.info.bind('clear requests'));
        }
      });

<script>
```

Comment: Thank you — I've seen that example, but where would I include it in my code? How do I trigger it to happen when the user accepts the apprequest?

Comment: are you coding via php ?

Comment: No, I have been using the Javascript SDK.

Comment: what about jquery is that included in your app?

Comment: JQuery is included in my app — and thanks for the sample code, but I still can't seem to get it working.

What I really need to know —— how does the code know that the user has accepted my application? Eventually I need to redirect them to a page within the Canvas URL using the data parameter on apprequests, but I'm completely stuck on how to manipulate the request IDS part of it.

Comment: one more question: are you asking users to install the app?
& you sent this requests to not installed users or installed users or for both

Comment: I GOT IT!! I didn't have the users installing the app correctly (my flow was leading them to the wrong place), so you were indeed correct. I had to take a few steps back before I could figure out where to place the delete requests.